# Why isn't the answer to this Atwood Machine problem correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, string

[image: Hi]

Given:
$$m_1 = 2*m_2$$
$$m_{disc} = 3*m_1 = 6*m_2$$
$$h = 3R$$ (R is the radius of the cylinder at the top)
Find $v^2$ in terms of $g$ and $r$, where $v$ is the velocity of the blocks when $m_1$ is just about to hit the floor. Assume that the string does not slip over the cylinder at the top, and that the cylinder does have a moment of inertia.

This was a problem that I found a while back, and I've been trying to solving it ever since. The correct answer is apparently $\frac{4}{3}gr$, but I keep on getting $gr$ as my answer. Here is my work:

We have the Conservation of Energy Equation
$$m_1gh = \frac{1}{2}m_1{v_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v_2}^2+m_2gh+\frac{1}{2}I{\omega}^2$$

First, we substitute in the first given equation to get
$$2m_2gh = m_2{v_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v_2}^2+m_2gh+\frac{1}{2}I{\omega}^2$$

Now, we calculate I to be
$$I_{disk} = \frac{1}{2}mr^2 = 0.5(3*m_1)r^2 = 1.5m_1r^2$$.

Substituting back in and combining like terms:
$$m_2gh = m_2{v_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v_2}^2+\frac{1}{2}(1.5m_1r^2){\omega}^2$$

Now, we realize that $$\omega = \frac{v}{r}$$, and also again use the first given equation:
$$m_2gh = m_2{v_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v_2}^2+\frac{1}{2}(1.5(2m_2)r^2)(\frac{v^2}{r^2})$$

Now, since $$h = 3R$$, we get
$$3m_2gr = m_2{v_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v_2}^2+1.5m_2v^2$$

Note that in this problem, v_1 = v_2, so
$$3m_2gr = m_2{v}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2{v}^2+1.5m_2v^2$$
$$3m_2gr = 3m_2v^2$$

Thus, we get
$$v^2 = \frac{3m_2gr}{3m_2}$$
So, $$v^2 = gr$$.

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time, and I don't know where my mistake is. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Book answers can be wrong. Show your teacher your work.

Comment: @BillN  Are you willing to state that the OP's answer is correct? That would be useful to him when he talks to his teacher.

Comment: Yes. I didn't find a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your answer is correct. I assume there is a mistake in the textbook, and they meant to write that $h=4R$. Then the textbook answer would have been right.

Comment: All too often, textbook publishers change the numbers provided in the exercises while forgetting to change the answers in the back of the book.